# Visualizing a Reinforcement Learning Agent's Progress

Tags: visualization, reinforcement-learning

I've seen a lot of posts that visualize a reinforcement agent's improvement as the training continues. They usually track the sum of all rewards or a moving average of winning percentage, but I don't think I ever read how they actually did it. Should I export the results of all sessions to a CSV file and then visualize it? Of course, the visualization part wouldn't be difficult, but I have always wondered how they collected data in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is essentially about collecting the sum of received rewards in an episode or evaluating the agent's success rate. Both methods are pretty much up to the programmer.

In the first case, it is usually done by implementing a method that performs one full episode and returns information about what happened in the episode. You can return several different statistics and it is only about your preferences - what do you want to keep track of. In case of the sum of rewards, you set up a variable (i.e. `total_reward`) with 0 as the initial value, and add observed rewards to this variable on each step. You then return the value of this variable on the end of the episode. You can collect these values for each episode in an outer loop - visualizing them after the learning has finished is, as you mentioned, not difficult.

In the case of evaluating success_rate, there are several approaches you can try out. You can add another information to the method mentioned above - whether the episode has ended in success or not (i.e. `is_success`). If you have collected such boolean value for each episode, you can aggregate information by calculating the percentage of 'success episodes' - for every 10 or more episodes - and then plot it.

The disadvantage of this approach is that these results may be inaccurate, due to the exploration technique you are using when the agent performs the episode. Already learned agent could not achieve successes that often if the exploration technique is having too much of an impact. That's why another option is frequently used for success rates: after every given number of episodes, you run your agent in an evaluation loop, where you let him choose actions without any exploration technique added (and you don't train the agent during this process!). The evaluation loop can consist of any number **N** of such test episodes (the more test episodes, the more exact evaluation is), and you calculate the success rate by simply counting the success episodes and divide this number by **N**. You save the evaluated success rates and log them during the training / visualize them after training finishes. Of course, you can calculate the moving average before plotting the values (I believe I don't have to explain this calculation here, though).

Personally, I use that second approach much more often - but you can clearly see, that this method adds much more time overhead. If you run your evaluation loop every 10 episodes, and the loop consists of 10 test episodes, you are *approximately* doubling the time of program execution. So, if the performance is already an issue, and the exploration technique is one that has a decaying impact over time, you might as well use the first, simpler version.

Last additional comment from me is - notice, that for total rewards you can actually do the same - instead of using values collected as I explained, an evaluation loop is also an option here. Because these values are usually pretty noisy and it is not so desired for them to be precise (it is more about seeing the trend), I've never seen someone do that. But nonetheless, you should be aware that one has many options and it all depends on how precise you need the values and how much overhead you can afford.

Comment: I had been calculating a success rate every 10 episodes, but it fluctuated too much, and that is why I decided to visualize it. I printed the comma-separated result of each episode to the console and visualized it using Excel, with which I'm familiar. [This is one of the visualizations.](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/7676354/49698174-9c2b8780-fc03-11e8-963c-4d925e1edaf6.png). Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You can check out how to visualize data directly from Python by using Matplotlib library (if not Python, just look for a plotting library for the language you are using). That way you can skip the 'export to CSV -> import to Excel' part and learn a very nice additional skill.